# How to clear Sitecore_reporting_log?

Tags: xdb

**Sitecore_reporting_log**

How to clear the above mentioned db?

The reason is the size of the db is keep on increasing, which is causing memory full.

I have enabled xDB.

If I clear will it affect any real time analytics data?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If your transaction log file is getting too large, this can indicate problems with your SQL server configuration, or possibly issues with your reporting Sitecore instance itself. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/troubleshoot-a-full-transaction-log-sql-server-error-9002

Comment: This is a SQL question, not a Sitecore question. You need to identify why your transactions are not being committed and space being reused by future logs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server